# Find start-end date of a week from week number

Tags: java, date, java-8

I build a web-application with servlet and JSPs and inside my Servlet I compute the number of the week:

```
 private int findWeekNumber(String myDate) 
    throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date;
        date = df.parse(myDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        System.out.println("week number is:" + week);

        return week;
    }
```

and then I save the `week` to my Database. Then I retrieve the `week` from my Database. How can I get the start - end dates of the week (Week start is Monday) from the `week`? Lets say the `weekNumber` is 30 and I want to compute the 20/07/2015 - 26/07/2015. The same function is [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html)

Comment: Can you use external libraries such as JodaTime or are you running on Java8? That might simplify things.

Comment: I am running Java8. I build a web-application with servlet and JSPs @reto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for this,

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
 Date yourDate = cal.getTime();

 cal.setTime(yourDate);//Set specific Date of which start and end you want

 Date start,end;

 cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
 start = cal.getTime();//Date of Monday of current week

 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);//Add 6 days to get Sunday of next week
 cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
 end = cal.getTime();//Date of Sunday of current week
 System.out.println(start +" - "+ end);
```

Comment: But you don't use week number to calculate the weekstart, weekEnd. The int variable `week` is my clue to compute the start/end dates

Comment: @Nat95 But you can use `date` as well. :) and `week` will give you at which position out of 52 your week stands.

Comment: Weeks don't always start on a Monday and end on a Sunday.

Comment: @TAsk forgive my but I don't understand how I will use the clue that I have, which is `int` var `week` (e.g. 30) in your code

Comment: I am saying that, because I save to my DB the `week`. When I retrieve it, i want then to calculate the start-end week dates.

Comment: @TAsk I get an exception `Exceptionn: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date`

Answer (score 10):

The Java 8 version

```
LocalDate week = LocalDate.now().with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, yourWeekNumber);

LocalDate start = week.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
LocalDate end = start.plusDays(6);
System.out.println(start +" - "+ end);
```

Comment: Two things: `LocalDate#with` is no static method, you need a LocalDate object (e.g. `LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1)`) to call the method. And the correct end date is `start.plusDays(6)`, not `week.plusDays(6)`.

Comment: Thanks, answer adjusted

Comment: You need to specify a time zone. If omitted, the JVM's current default time zone is applied. Time zone is crucial in deterring the date. A new day dawns earlier in Paris, for example, than Montréal.

Comment: Is there no better solution? Throwing away a `LocalDate` instance doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        int weekNumber = 34;
        System.out.printf("%s - %s%n", getFirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, Locale.UK),
                getLastDayOfWeek(weekNumber, Locale.UK));
        System.out.printf("%s - %s%n", getFirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, Locale.US),
                getLastDayOfWeek(weekNumber, Locale.US));
    }

    static LocalDate getFirstDayOfWeek(int weekNumber, Locale locale) {
        return LocalDate
                .of(Year.now().getValue(), 2, 1)
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek())
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekNumber);
    }

    static LocalDate getLastDayOfWeek(int weekNumber, Locale locale) {
        return getFirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, locale).plusDays(6);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-23 - 2021-08-29
2021-08-15 - 2021-08-21
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jI5o2H)

Note that the ***first day of the week*** is `Locale`-dependent e.g. it is Monday in the UK while Sunday in the US. As per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards, it is Monday. For comparison, check the [US calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=1&wno=1) and the [UK calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=9&wno=1).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From week number:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);


calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
   // Now get the first day of week.
Date sDate = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(sDate);

calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, (week));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
Date eDate = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(eDate);
```

**Another Solution**

Iff - without week number

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -dayOfWeek);

Date weekStart = c.getTime();
// we do not need the same day a week after, that's why use 6, not 7
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6); 
Date weekEnd = c.getTime();

System.out.println(weekStart);
System.out.println(weekEnd);
```

Comment: You don't use week number to calculate the weekstart, weekEnd. The int variable `week` is my clue to compute the start/end dates.